# How can one cancel an upload in JupyterLab?

Tags: file-upload, jupyter-lab, cancellation

I am uploading several large files via JupyterLab:

[image]

How can I cancel the upload?

Comment: I don't think this is possible other than refreshing the browser tab or using the Network tab of the developer tools. I would suggest opening an enhancement request on [JupyterLab issues](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues) page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [krassowski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6646912/krassowski) [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77738191/how-can-one-cancel-an-upload-in-jupyterlab#comment137071106_77738191), currently the only way  to cancel an upload in JupyterLab is to reload the browser  tab.